# How to edit m4b audiobook metadata in Catalina?

Tags: catalina, books, metadata, id3-tag, audiobook

In Catalina it is not possible to edit audiobook metadata anymore as it was possible using iTunes in previous macOS versions. I tried a third-party tag editor ([kid3](https://sourceforge.net/projects/kid3/)), successfully edited the audiobook metadata, but still, when I import the audiobook into the Books app, the metadata is wrong.

What could possibly be going on, is there anyway I can work around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I used subler BY Damiano Galassi to change it.